# Write a specific movie clip to bitmap in Adobe AIR

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air, screenshot

I am developing a game for iOS in Adobe AIR and I want to take a screenshot (or the bitmap capture of a specific portion/movie clip of the screen). I've read that it is possible with a native extension to take screenshots, but I don't actually need the whole screen, I just need the bitmap representation of a specific movie clip (or screen area, if possible) within Adobe AIR. I don't think I need access to native SDKs to achieve this, but I couldn't find any resources to achieve what I'm trying to do.

How can I save a 'bitmap snapshot' of a movie clip in Adobe AIR, **without** using native extensions?

Thanks,

Can.

Comment: movie clip as in .swf or .mp4?

Comment: regular flash movieclip object as in swf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're only going to need a snapshot of content from within your air app(e.g. MovieClip/other DisplayObject), you can use BitmapData's [draw()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#draw%28%29) method:

```
/*
* getSnapshot - simple snapshot of a DisplayObject
* @param matrix - the transformation matrix of the object to be drawn(translation/rotation/scale)
*                 use this parameter to include the object's tranformations or an arbitrary one. 
*                 Ex. getSnapshot(myClip,myClip.transform.concatenatedMatrix);
* @param coordinateSpace - the coordinate space from used to get bounds. if you're object's rotated, 
*                          the by passing null, the bitmap will include all contents, otherwise it will be
*                          clipped using the original/'unrotated' bounds.
*/
function getSnapshot(obj:DisplayObject,matrix:Matrix = null,coordinateSpace:DisplayObject = null):BitmapData{
    var bounds:Rectangle = obj.getBounds(coordinateSpace);
    var result:BitmapData = new BitmapData(bounds.width,bounds.height,true,0x00FFFFFF);
    result.draw(obj,matrix);
    return result;
}
```

e.g.

```
var test:Shape = addChild(new Shape()) as Shape;
test.graphics.beginFill(0);test.graphics.drawRect(0,0,100,100);test.graphics.endFill();

var snapShot:Bitmap = addChild(new Bitmap(getSnapshot(test))) as Bitmap;
snapShot.x = test.width+10;

function getSnapshot(obj:DisplayObject,matrix:Matrix = null,coordinateSpace:DisplayObject = null):BitmapData{
    var bounds:Rectangle = obj.getBounds(coordinateSpace);
    var result:BitmapData = new BitmapData(bounds.width,bounds.height,true,0x00FFFFFF);
    result.draw(obj,matrix);
    return result;
}
```